# End date shown on calendar

Tags: datetime

I'm using the Calendar, and Date modules to create an agenda on a website. However, when I create an event with a start and end date, it also shows the event on the next day. While this is useful for true multiple day events, it is not for party that start late and end late, as I want them to only show once (at the start date).

Is it possible to fix this?

[image: screenshot]

For clarification: I'm using the Date (ISO format) field.

Comment: Could you clarify what the actual start date and end date values are in your example, please?

Answer (score 0):

I would check your date/time settings, specifically the sites default time zone.  I have seen similar errors when that is set incorrectly.

Comment: Checked these settings, still behaving this way

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the end date is not really important in terms of using the calendar itself, so why not addding the end date as an additional field for information purposes only?

Answer (score 0):

try to follow below steps: it may solve your problem.

1. go to contextual filter under advanced tab in views.
2. select date(node). then in configuration of this date(node), select only the starting date in date field. and check method as AND.

This will display only the starting date on your calender.